# Moving a Git branch to a different respository

Tags: git, gitlab

How can I add an existing Git branch to another repository. Both repositories are on the same internal Gitlab server, and I don't care about maintaining the existing history of this branch.

Answer (score 2):

Assume the two repos in the server are RSa and RSb, which can be accessed via `git://xxx.yyy.zz/RSa.git` and `git://xxx.yyy.zz/RSb.git`. The target is add RSa's branch `refs/heads/bsa-dev` to RSb.

In your local machine,

```
git init work
cd work
git fetch git://xxx.yyy.zz/RSa.git refs/heads/bsa-dev
git push git://xxx.yyy.zz/RSb.git FETCH_HEAD:refs/heads/bsa-dev
```